# Javascript: Modify array directly only within its own function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very simple function:

```
 var errorsViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;                
            var _errors = ko.observableArray([]);    
            self.get = function () {
                return _errors;
            };    
            self.insert = function ( error ) {
                _errors.push(error);
            };  
   }
```

What I want to acomplish is make `_errors` array modifiable directly only within its own function. That is users from outside can get the array for reading through the `get` method and insert itsert items only through the `insert` method.

But not to be able to do something like this:

```
var err = new errorsViewModel();
var array = err.get();
array.push('item');
```

Instead use the errorsViewModel interface :

```
err.insert('some error');
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Return an object that exposes only read functions instead of returning the array as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the returned array:

```
self.get = function () {
    return _errors.slice(0);
};
```

That way, when `get` is called, the caller can make changes to it if they want - but it won't modify the original.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that your array isn't accessible from outside your scope I would suggest that you expose the array via a `ko.computed` and then notify it's listeners on an insert.

```
var errorsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;                
    var _errors = [];    

    self.errors = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.get();
    });

    self.get = function () {
        return _errors.splice(0);
    };    

    self.insert = function ( error ) {
        _errors.push(error);
        self.errors.valueHasMutated();
    };  
}
```